# Char array outputting extra characters

Tags: c++, arrays, char, compare

Hello this is a segment of my code of which i am trying to implement the Morris-Pratt algorithm.
When i am comparing my variables if find that they dont match, this is because one of my variables "Temp" is geting extra characters added to the end of the array.
here is my code...

```
        // Calculate the next talbe
        char test[searchLen];

        for(int i = 0; i < searchLen; i++)
        {   
            test[i] = fileContent[currPos+i];
        }

        cout << "SEARCHLEN: " << searchLen << endl;
        cout << "TEST: " << '\t' << '\t' << test << endl;
        cout << "SEARCH: " << '\t' << search << endl;
        cout << strcmp(test,search) << endl << endl;
        // Determine if a match is detected

        if(strcmp(test,search)==0)
        {
            cout << "----------------------> Match detected at: " << currPos << endl;
        }

        currPos ++;
    }

    return numberOfComparisons;
}
```

The output looks like this...

```
SEARCHLEN: 8
TEST:       athsoutg5?h
SEARCH:     brilling
-1
```

As you can see the 5?H is not supposed to be there and is breaking my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a null terminator.

```
   char test[searchLen + 1];
   test[searchLen] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 1):

It does look like your string is not terminated with \0, maybe you forgot to copy it / put it in there?